# iOS 8 Xcode 6.1 Swift prepareForSegue Controller which is already presenting (null)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I get the following warning:

> Warning: Attempt to present StartViewController: 0x7ff418e1be30  on StartViewController: 0x7ff418c4ab50 which is already presenting (null)

My Code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // 1
    if segue.identifier == "Add" {

        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choices", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        let button1action: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "First Choice", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> () in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("first", sender: self)
        })
        let button2action: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Second choice", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> () in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: self)
        })
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(button1action)
        alertController.addAction(button2action)


      self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

If I press the "Add"-Button in the ViewController, the Alert will popup, and the warn message too.
The controller call itself in the last line of the code, but I have no solution to fix it.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in `prepareForSegue` it means you've already triggered a `segue`, so the presentation of some view controller has already started.

You should not be calling `presentViewController` from `prepareFromSegue` but use it to set up the `destination` view controller instead.

For this case, I think when you `Add`, instead of triggering a segue you need to trigger an `IBAction` and move that code there instead.

Comment: Beat me to it, but spot on.